# How to iterate over a Stream in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning the rope with Dart, after years of python.
I am a bit confused about Streams and if there is any other particular solution I can use for my specific case.

I am building an API driven app, and I need to populate a ListView dynamically without needing to wait for all the HTTP calls to finish. 
At the moment I am using a Stream which populates a List with yields as a return:

Something like this:

```
var scraperList = List<Api> ();

Stream<List<Api>> get getFiles (String id) async* {
    var res = await http.post('${baseUrl}/folder/list/{id}');
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResult = jsonDecode(res.body);
      jsonResult = jsonResult['content'];
      List<dynamic> body = jsonResult;
      List<Api> result = body.map((dynamic item) => ApiModel.apiFiles(item),).toList();
}
```

Now, this is where I am lost, as the API acts as a sort of file/folder storage I need to yields the results if they are "files", and repeat the call with the id of the folder and get the "files" inside that folder and keep doing that until I get all the files inside each folder recursively.

The point is I want to keep feeding that Stream and get the results as they arrive without the need to wait for all the calls to complete.

where I am lost at the moment is this part

```
      // THIS IS THE PART I NEED TO UNDERSTAND YET
      for (item in result){
        if (item.type == 'file'){
          yield filelist.add(0, item);}
        else { I NEED TO MAKE A CALL AGAIN TO THIS FUNCTION TO GET THE FOLDER CONTENT
             THE CALL AGAIN }
```

How can I iterate over this API, get all the files in every folder recursively and keep feeding that Stream?
Is there a better way to do this?
In python, there are a lot of ways to share a list across classes and so on but I am still confused about how to achieve this dynamically in Dart.

Answer (score 2):

While this answer may come too late for you (after 3 years), it could still be helpful for others who encounter similar issues in the future.

Saed might misunderstood your intention, who provided an answer on converting an `Iterator` to a `Stream`, rather than iterating over a `Stream` (may be equivalent to converting a `Stream` to an `Iterator`).

As far as I know, it may be impossible to do it. But there is a so similar solution -- using [`StreamIterator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamIterator-class.html). It has the similar interface to `Iterator`. The difference is its methods are asynchronous. For example, you should use `await streamIterator.moveNext()` instead of `iterator.moveNext()`.

Converting a `Stream` to a `StreamIterator` is so easy, just use `final streamIterator = StreamIterator(yourStream);`.

It may be difficult to share functions between `Iterator` and `StreamIterator` because `Iterator` has synchronous methods. Currently, I am achieving this by converting `Iterable` to `Stream` and then converting it to `StreamIterator`:

`final streamIterator = StreamIterator(Stream.fromIterable(iterable));`

Please let me know if there is any more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is yield* and await

check this

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {

  final folder1 = Future.value({"a","b","c","d"});
  final folder2 = Future.value({"a","b","c","d",folder1});
  final folder3 = {"a","b","c","d",folder1,folder2}; //what you get initially

  Stream printElement(list) async*{

     for(dynamic element in list){

      if(element is String){
        yield element;
       }else{
        yield* printElement(
        await(element));  //make your http call here for your nested folder
        }

     };
  }

  printElement(folder3).listen((element){
      print(element);
  });

}
```

You can also use **more type safe** code with `Either` from [dartz package](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

class MyFile{

  final String fileName ;

  MyFile(this.fileName);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return this.fileName;
  }
}

class MYFolder{

  final String folderName;
  final List<Either<Future<MYFolder>,MyFile>> files; //files can be Either file or Future of folder from HTTP

  MYFolder(this.folderName, this.files);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return this.folderName;
  }
}

void main() {

  //leaf folders

  final foldera = MYFolder("foldera",[Right(MyFile("a")),Right(MyFile("a")),Right(MyFile("a")),Right(MyFile("a"))]);
  final folderb = MYFolder("folderb",[Right(MyFile("b")),Right(MyFile("b")),Right(MyFile("b")),Right(MyFile("b"))]);
  final folderc = MYFolder("folderc",[Right(MyFile("c")),Right(MyFile("c")),Right(MyFile("c")),Right(MyFile("c"))]);
  final folderd = MYFolder("folderd",[Right(MyFile("d")),Right(MyFile("d")),Right(MyFile("d")),Right(MyFile("d"))]);

  //                    ...foldera
  //                   - folderb
  //        -  folder1
  //
  //folder3 -  folder2
  //                  ... folderc
  //                  - folderd
  //
  // --triple dot notation for folding elements in lists ,it is just a shortcut for populating lists

  final  folder1 = Future.value(MYFolder("folder1", [...foldera.files,Left(Future.value(folderb))]));
  final folder2 = Future.value(MYFolder("folder2", [...folderc.files, Left(Future.value(folderd))]));
  final folder3 = MYFolder("folder3",[Left(Future.value(folder1)),Left(Future.value(folder2))]); //what you get initially

  Stream printFilesIn(MYFolder folder) async*{

    print("Current folder is $folder");

     for(Either file in folder.files){
      if(file is Right){
        yield file.value;
      }else{
        yield* printFilesIn(
        await(file as Left).value); //make your http call here for your nested folder
        }
      };
  }

  printFilesIn(folder3).listen(print);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams), you can use the **await for** keyword like that:

```
Future<int> sumStream(Stream<int> stream) async {
  var sum = 0;
  await for (final value in stream) {
    sum += value;
  }
  return sum;
}
```